# Post option value to mysql via ajax wont work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-select

i have been working on some project and getting some experience on php and ajax, jquery. So i have checked 20+ question on stackoverflow but couldnt find the solution even if its already answered the same question.

I have tryed 10 diffrent solution but i guess im skipping something.
I have simple select box and im using ajax to send mysql but only select box doesnt work for some reason.

HTML Code:

```
     <section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex flex-column" id="rezervasyon">
      <div class="my-auto">
        <h2 class="mb-5">Online Rezervasyon</h2>

        <form id="loginForm" method="" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="rez_ad" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">İsim Soyisim</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rez_ad" id="rez_ad" placeholder="İsim Soyisim">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="rez_saat" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Rezervasyon Saati</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rez_saat" id="rez_saat" placeholder="Rezervasyon saati">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="rez_gsm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cep Numaranız</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="rez_gsm" id="rez_gsm" placeholder="İletişim numaranız.">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="rez_tarih" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Tarih</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="rez_tarih" id="rez_tarih" placeholder="Tarih belirtiniz.">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="rez_email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="rez_email" id="rez_email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
           <label for="rez_tip" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" name="rez_tip" id="rez_tip">Rezervasyon Tipi</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select id="rez_tip" class="custom-select">

              <option value="" selected>Rezervasyon Tipi Seçiniz</option>
              <option value="1">Cuma Fix Menü</option>
              <option value="2">Cumartesi Fix Menü</option>
              <option value="3">Haftaiçi ALKOLSÜZ</option>
              <option value="4">Haftaiçi ALKOLLÜ</option>
              <option value="5">Kutlama / Doğum Günü</option>
              <option value="6">Diğer</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="rez_sayi" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" id="rez_sayi" name="rez_sayi">Kişi Sayısı</label>
         <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select id="rez_sayi" class="custom-select">

            <option value="" selected>Kişi Sayısı Belirtiniz</option>
            <option value="1">2 Kişilik Rezervasyon</option>
            <option value="2">4 Kişilik Rezervasyon</option>
            <option value="3">4+ Kişilik Rezervasyon</option>
            <option value="4">6+ Kişilik Rezervasyon</option>
            <option value="5">8+ Kişilik Rezervasyon</option>
            <option value="6">20+ Kişilik Rezervasyon</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>
      <textarea name="rez_aciklama" id="rez_aciklama" class="form-control" rows="6" cols="21" required="required"
      placeholder="Ek açıklama girebilirsiniz."></textarea>

      <form class="was-validated">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>


                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="right-side">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-link">Delete</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">

          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlValidation1" required>

          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlValidation1">Rezervasyon Şartlarını Kabul Ediyorum!</label>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Rezervasyon şartlarını okuyunuz!</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="insert-data" id="insert-data" onclick="insertData()">Rezervasyonu Tamamla</button>

</div>
</div>
<br>
<p id="message"></p>
</form>
```

Here is my php file ;

```
    <?php

include('db.php');
$rez_ad=$_POST['rez_ad'];
$rez_saat=$_POST['rez_saat'];
$rez_gsm=$_POST['rez_gsm'];
$rez_tarih=$_POST['rez_tarih'];
$rez_tip=$_POST['rez_tip'];
$rez_sayi=$_POST['rez_sayi'];
$rez_aciklama=$_POST['rez_aciklama'];

$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO student(rez_ad,rez_saat,rez_gsm,rez_tarih,rez_tip,rez_sayi,rez_aciklama) VALUES(:rez_ad, :rez_saat,:rez_gsm,:rez_tarih,:rez_tip,:rez_sayi,:rez_aciklama)");

$stmt->bindparam(':rez_ad', $rez_ad);
$stmt->bindparam(':rez_saat', $rez_saat);
$stmt->bindparam(':rez_gsm', $rez_gsm);
$stmt->bindparam(':rez_tarih', $rez_tarih);
$stmt->bindparam(':rez_tip', $rez_tip);
$stmt->bindparam(':rez_sayi', $rez_sayi);
$stmt->bindparam(':rez_aciklama', $rez_aciklama);
if($stmt->execute())
{
  $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
  $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
  echo json_encode($error);
}



 ?>
```

Here is my jquery code;

```
    function insertData() {
      var rez_ad=$("#rez_ad").val();
      var rez_saat=$("#rez_saat").val();
      var rez_gsm=$("#rez_gsm").val();
      var rez_tarih=$("#rez_tarih").val();
      var rez_tip=$("#rez_tip").val();
      var rez_sayi=$("#rez_sayi").val();
      var rez_aciklama=$("#rez_aciklama").val();


    // AJAX code to send data to php file.
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "rez/insert-data.php",
      data: {rez_ad:rez_ad,rez_saat:rez_saat,rez_gsm:rez_gsm,rez_tarih:rez_tarih,rez_tip:rez_tip,rez_sayi:rez_sayi,rez_aciklama:rez_aciklama},
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
       $("#message").html(data);
       $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
     },
     error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
    });

    }
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: could you add php code here for more information

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What does work?  Any errors? Without more specifics is hard to help since code shown is structurally ok and you provided virtually no debugging info. Note you have 2 variables but only send one in the data object

Comment: You also aren't showing how insertData() even gets called

Comment: I have removed working php codes from the script and php files. 
"rez_sayi" and "rez_tip" is option value on html file. But when i post it to mysql i cant see both of them, rest of them is okey which like i said i've removed it before i post here so you can see it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should then pass the `rez_tip` option in ajax call also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function insertData() {
  //var rez_tip=$("#rez_tip option:selected").text();
  //var rez_sayi=$("#rez_sayi option:selected").text();
  var rez_tip=$("select#rez_tip").val();
  var rez_sayi=$("select#rez_sayi").val();


  // AJAX code to send data to php file.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rez/insert-data.php",
        data: {rez_sayi:rez_sayi,rez_tip:rez_tip},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
         $("#message").html(data);
        $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
        },
        error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
        }
    });

   }

 </script>
```

Comment: I have added full code can you check them again because its already same.

Comment: there is no error all data posting on mysql except rez_tip and rez_sayi. on phpmyadmin

Comment: @AlperAslan please see my updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EvilsEmpire/j4n67caf/

Comment: You are my hero <3 Thank you so much !!